# What does ldapsearch response mean?

Tags: openldap

I created a ldap directory with a number of users and groups. When I query this directory from a remote server with:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://ldap.myserver.net/ -x -vvvvvvv -b dc=myserver,dc=net -D cn=admin,dc=myserver,dc=net -W
```

I get all objects in the directory returned. The result finishes with the following:

```
# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 85
# numEntries: 84
```

What do these numbers mean exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"search: 2"
2 is the messageID of the search operation.

"result: 0 Success"
0 is the error code.  Here is a list of the others
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/quebec-platform-administration/page/administer/reference-pages/reference/r_LDAPErrorCodes.html

"numResponses: 85"
85 is the number of pieces of information returned including the meta information.

"numEntries: 84"
84 is the total number of entries that the search returned.

Comment: Thanks! I was totally thrown of by the search ... result 0. Interpreting that it actually deliverd zero results.

Comment: So how do you get the results instead of just a `numResponses`?